# Remove duplicates based on next row

Tags: r, duplicates, shift

I'm new to R. I'm looking to remove duplicate rows in a data frame where `df$x = "string"` **AND** `the next row = the same string`

so say I have this column

`1. String - remove
 2. String 
 3. A
 4. A
 5. A
 6. String  - remove
 7. String  - remove
 8. String 
 9. A
 10. A`

The result I want would be

`2. String
 3. A
 4. A
 5. A
 8. String
 9. A
 10. A`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `lead` from `dplyr` and remove rows where the current and next row is "String".

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(!(V1 == "String" & lead(V1) == "String"))

#      V1
#1 String
#2      A
#3      A
#4 String
#5      A
```

---

Using base R, we can do

```
df[!((df$V1 == "String") & c(df$V1[-1], NA) == "String"),,drop = FALSE]

#      V1
#2 String
#3      A
#4      A
#7 String
#8      A
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("String", "String", "A", "A", "String", 
"String", "String", "A")), .Names = "V1", row.names = c(NA, -8L
 ), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Yes!! I used the base R option :)

Answer (score 0):

We could create a logical index with `duplicated` and `rleid` for subsetting the rows

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[!(duplicated(rleid(V1)) & V1 == 'String')]
#       V1
#1: String
#2:      A
#3:      A
#4: String
#5:      A
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("String", "String", "A", "A", "String", 
"String", "String", "A")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```